# Java: Change an objects value without changing all references

Tags: java, object, reference, a-star

This is probably a noob question, but i just don't get it.

I am trying to implement A* pathfinding in my game. I was following [this tutorial](http://www.cokeandcode.com/main/tutorials/path-finding/) and the code in the `AstarPathfinder.java`. But instead of instantiating the AStarPathfinder class and having an 2D Array for all `Nodes` i made a static method, to which i pass my 2D Array (the Level/World), start and end Node.
Cause of this i always have to store the current and the next `Node` in a `Node next` and `Node current`. I then add them to the open or closed list (depends on where they belong) and change the x and y value (position) of the `Node` with their setter method, to have the next node.

After a few minutes of debuging i noticed that this (ofc) changes also the value of the node inside the `openList` and `closedList`. To prevent this i can simply call `next = new Node(int x, int y)` instead of only setting the values, but as my Pathfinding is running every few render loops it would mess up garbage collection and cost a lot of performance. So i am looking for a possibility to have one `Node` variable, which i can instantiate once with default constructor, and then change its value without changing its value in the list.

Is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is not a direct answer to your question, hopefully it will help you make a good decision

The JVM has become very good at re-using objects and you should generally not be afraid to use the **new** keyword.

For more detailed reading, see [should-we-avoid-object-creation-in-java](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/149563/should-we-avoid-object-creation-in-java)

Comment: So this is no real problem anymore? Thats good. As i allready wrote on the other answer i heard that creating new objects in the render method (method called every gameloop) causes huge performance issues. Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm on the same page as Eric Stein here, don't do premature optimizations, if your program runs fine, it's fine. If your program doesn't run fine, find the bottleneck and fix it.

Comment: Okay thanks for your answer. I will try the `new` operator and look at the performance. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is not possible. You only have one instance of a Node object, with pointers to that object in multiple locations. You need to make new Node instances.

> it would mess up garbage collection and cost a lot of performance

If you haven't done performance testing and shown that this is an unacceptable bottleneck, you should not assume this.

Comment: I am working with libgdx and many tutorials there suggested to use pooling to avoid creating `new` objects. So i thought this will be really performance heavy. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Springrbua Well, I don't know anything about libgdx, so I can't speak to that API in particular. I would suggest trying to make new nodes and see if there are performance issues or not. If so, you can always ask another question here, perhaps with the libgdx tag and some of the troublesome source code.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot. Now i just don't know which answer i should accept as you both helped me... :P