# New object changing values

Tags: java

In my code, I am removing an element from the preferences list. For that, I defined a new object using

```
 Preferences pref= new Preferences(preferences.getNumberOfProfessors(),preferences.getNumberOfStudents(),preferences.getProfessors_preference(),preferences.getStudents_preference());
```

Now, i declared a new array list of array list as-

```
 ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> prof_pref_bup=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
 prof_pref_bup=pref.getProfessors_preference();
```

Now, when I perform prof_pref_bup.remove(0), the preference list of the professor all the way upto the preference object gets changed. Could someone help me?

PS- I cannot change the Preference class and therefore cannot use the copy constructor.

I already went through 
[Java: Change an objects value without changing all references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22354115/java-change-an-objects-value-without-changing-all-references)
and similar posts on SO!

Comment: It's the same reference you're modifying. Create a copy instead: `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> prof_pref_bup = new ArrayList<>(pref.getProfessors_preference());`

Comment: It didnt work out!

Comment: I'm sorry to hear!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to make *prof_pref_bup* as copy of *pref.getProfessors_preference()*, you can do something like this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> prof_pref_bup = new ArrayList<>();
for (ArrayList<Integer> entry : pref.getProfessors_preference()) {
    prof_pref_bup.add(new ArrayList<>(entry));
}
```

So now *prof_pref_bup* is a new ArrayList with a list of values copied exactly from *pref.getProfessors_preference()*